# How to use Exchange Impersonation via outlook redemption

Tags: outlook-redemption

On exchange 2010, LogonExchangeMailbox() is able to access multiple mailboxes using the current window credential.

```
session.LogonExchangeMailbox(userOne, mailServer)
session.LogonExchangeMailbox(userTwo, mailServer)
```

On exchange 2013, what's the proper way? It's a vb script, I don't want the user password hardcoded in the file. I tried something like but can't make it work:

```
session.Logon()
session.UseEWSImpersonation=1
credential=session.credentials
session.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox(userOne@mail.com, credential)
session.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox(userTne@mail.com, credential)
```

I also tried AddDelegateExchangeMailBoxStore(user), but if I accidentially added twice, one will not be able to delete.

Outlook redemption is latest version with Outlook 2013 on Win 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LogonExchangeMailbox` uses the credentials of the current domain user to connect. If you want to open a mailbox of another user, logon to the current user's mailbox using `LogonExchangeMailbox`, then open another user's mailbox using `RDOSession.GetSharedMailbox`

Comment: Since I got MAPI_E_NETWORK_ERROR when using LogonExchangeMailbox, just thought that was not supported on exchange 2013.

Comment: Thanks, I think too complicated from the impersonation c# sample, the following works:  
    session.Logon()
    store=session.GetSharedMailbox(userOne)
    store=session.GetSharedMailbox(userTwo)

Comment: MAPI_E_NETWORK_ERROR  in the context of LogonExchangeMailbox means you are trying to connect to an Exchange Server using the old RPC protocol, which Exchange 2016 no longer supports - use LogonHostedExchangeMailbox, it uses RPC-over-HTTP.